# Python : How can I test that my error has been logged on sentry?

Tags: python, logging, sentry, raven

I have integrate my python default logger with raven . Now my errors are being logged on sentry.io/my_app. But I wanted to ask is there any way we can write unit tests for this function that generates an error and then somehow confirm that this error exits on sentry.

Answer (score 3):

In Raven-Python you can implement a [custom transport](https://docs.sentry.io/clients/python/transports/) to swap out the HTTP request for a simple callback. This is done by implementing an abstract class for which there does not exist a lot of documentation unfortunately and the data you get is a bytestring of json-encoded data. You can find the abstract class here: https://github.com/getsentry/raven-python/blob/285b257cf386bfac78f6fe334c9044af65f98561/raven/transport/base.py#L26

This is slightly easier in [the new SDK](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/python/) where you can write (without providing a DSN):

```
events = []
init(transport=events.append)
```

to collect events into an array instead of sending them to a server.

Answer (score -1):

You can use pytest  https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/ to write unit tests for your code. However sentry is used for monitoring of application which helps you to fix bug as per priority. Rather than confirming an error message from sentry, fixing the error by looking into sentry is more useful.

Comment: No. My sole purpose to post this question was to ask is there any way I can test that error is logged. We write unit tests for each line of code in our project.